# Regular expression for this function

Tags: python, regex

I want to simplify this function, using regular expressions.
the sample input can be

```
text =' At&T, " < I am > , At&T  so  &#60; &lt; &  & '
```

My code:

```
def replaceentity(text):
    import re
    import uuid
    from cgi import escape
    invalid_chars_map = {'&':'&#38;', '<':'&#60;', '>': '&#62;', '"': "&#34;"}
    replace_values = {'&lt;':'&#60;', '&gt;':'&#62;'}
    replaced_dict = {}
    for key, value in replace_values.items():
        text = text.replace(key, value)
    print "after replace >>>>>>  " + text
    for word in text.split():
        if word in invalid_chars_map.values():
            print word
            uid = str(uuid.uuid4())
            text = text.replace(word, uid)
            replaced_dict[uid] = word
    text = escape(text)
    for i in replaced_dict.keys():
        text = text.replace(i, replaced_dict[i])
    print text
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> from cgi import escape
>>> escaped = escape("""'At&T, " < I am > , At&T  so  &#60; &lt """)
>>> escaped
'\'At&amp;T, " &lt; I am &gt; , At&amp;T  so  &amp;#60; &amp;lt '
```

Comment: no ... as you can see in logic of my code if the value is already present in the dictionary i want to skip that word as it is i.e dont want to replace & from that